# error[E0601]: `main` function not found in crate for utilitary file for a custom binary

Tags: rust

I have a custom binary called `cli.rs` and a file `clap.rs` with some utilities for `clap.rs`:

```
src
  bin
    cli.rs
    clap.rs
```

where clap.rs just provides me with the clap definitions:

```
pub fn get_matches() -> ArgMatches {

}

fn main() {}
```

so I can import them into `cli.rs`.

However if I take out `fn main` from `clap.rs` I get

```
error[E0601]: `main` function not found in crate `clap`
```

I don't want `clap.rs` to have a main function, I just it to simply be a utils file for the binary `cli.rs`

Comment: Either make clap.rs a library crate as opposed to a binary or add #[no_main] to clap.rs

Comment: @Custards1 I added `#![no_main]` to the top of `clap.rs` but I get an undefined reference to main when linking

Answer (score 0):

From the cargo book about [package layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html):

> Cargo uses conventions for file placement to make it easy to dive into a new Cargo package:
>
> ```
> .
> // ...
> ├── src/
> |   | // ...
> │   └── bin/
> │       ├── named-executable.rs
> │       ├── another-executable.rs
> │       └── multi-file-executable/
> │           ├── main.rs
> │           └── some_module.rs
> | // ...
> ```
>
> - *[...]*
> - The default executable file is src/main.rs.
>
>   - Other executables can be placed in src/bin/.
> - *[...]*
>
> If a binary, example, bench, or integration test consists of multiple source files, place a `main.rs` file along with the extra modules within a subdirectory of the `src/bin`, `examples`, `benches`, or `tests` directory. The name of the executable will be the directory name.

By putting both `cli.rs` and `clap.rs` into `bin/`, you told Cargo that you have **two** binaries: One named `cli`, one named `clap`.

This package layout should work for you:

```
src
  bin
    cli
      main.rs (that's your cli.rs)
      clap.rs
```

Alternatively, you could also put `clap.rs` into a lib crate (by putting it inside `lib/` and then putting `pub mod clap;` inside `lib.rs`). Note however that you then need to reference `get_matches()` as `<your_package_name>::clap::get_matches()` so that the compiler knows you are not referencing something from your binary crate, but something from your library crate.